# How to update/reveal in Finder using Applescript

Tags: applescript, finder

Here is what I would like to do:

```
IF file is already present in a finder window
    tell finder to update...
ELSE
    tell finder to reveal...
```

Is there a way to determine if the file in question is already displayed in a current Finder window? I do not want to end up creating a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Lauri ... you should switch your comment to an answer. That works on Snow Leopard as well.  tell application "Finder" to reveal alias "Mac OS X:Users:John:Desktop:testFolder:test.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reveal` command should already work that way. `activate` focuses Finder if another application is frontmost:

```
tell application "Finder"
    reveal POSIX file "/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html"
    activate
end tell
```